# Can a sub resource change its "parent" resource in REST?

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee

If I do a POST to /quizzes/1/answer/final I want the answer to be saved on the server, but I also want to set a submitted date on the quiz resource as well as update the status of the quiz to done. Can I do that when I POST to the URI mentioned or should I do another request where I update the quiz-resource?

Since I want the workflow to be on the server, I don't want the client to do to much, but I don't know if changing another resource when I am posting an answer is right either?

What should I respond with from this POST?

Should I respond with the answer and a 20x, a 303 pointing to the answer, a 303 pointing to the quiz etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately the transitions of state on your server and your response resources are up to you and your requirements. REST is only a guide.

I personally agree that if the state of the quiz resource should change with a particular action I would do so, as you then save a RTT and client complexity.

Edit to add: Also when writing any service, I start with the assumption that the client will lie to me. If the client is responsible for submitting the answer then appropriately updating the quiz, what's to stop a client from submitting an answer and then setting the time of the quiz to 30 years ago or a [thousand years in the future](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5239)?

As far as a successful response from the POST, I think it would depend on what should the client do next. If they might want to go either direction an option could be a 200 with the submitted answer (the resource at the current uri, as a confirmation), and canonical links to the answer and a link to the overall quiz. I would lean toward 200 as it clearly indicates success, however that is an opinion, and again how would your intended client behave. (Is it a browser or a programmatic client or both? That might influence your decision)